# Java.Lang.VerifyError on Android API 10

Tags: android, sqliteopenhelper, verifyerror

I get the following error when executing android app on emulator Nexus S Platform 2.3.3 with api 10. It works well on Nexus 4 Android 4.3 with api 18. AppDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper.

Code:

```
 public class AppController extends Application {

     [...]

     private static AppDatabase mDbo;

     [...]
     try {
         // Here comes the crash, it crashes immediately, i cannot step into 
         mDbo = new AppDatabase( AppDatabase.NAME,null, new AppSQLiteCursor(),AppDatabase.VERSION) ;

      }
  }
```

Error stacktrace:

```
12-14 23:04:01.996    1372-1372/com.example.myapp E/APP_ERROR﹕ VerifyError raised!
    java.lang.VerifyError: com.example.myapp.database.AppDatabase
            at com.example.myapp.AppController.onCreate(AppController.java:85)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:969)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3272)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:117)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:969)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Without the code to `AppDatabase`, it will be very difficult for anyone to help you. I would look at your data members and see if any of them are of a data type that does not exist on API Level 10. You can also manually run Lint to have it point out your problem, assuming you have not used annotations or something to block it.

Comment: @CommonsWare, thanks for your reply, check my edit maybe that clarifies the question a little better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally found out the culprit for the VerifyError exception. It was due to SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException, which was not included until API 11. Using only SQLiteException to catch the errors in AppDatabase class did the job.